# What's the difference in perforce between a filetype of +S and +S1?

Tags: perforce

According to the Perforce [documentation](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4guide/Content/P4Guide/filetypes.modifiers.html), setting a filetype of +S (with no number after it) indicates "only the head revision is stored".

Using a number, as in "+Sn", means "Only the most recent n revisions are stored, where n is a number from 1 to 10, or 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, or 512."

Does this mean that +S1 is identical to +S? Or does +S save only the head revision, and +S1 saves the head revision plus one more?

Comment: Yes, +S is the same as +S1.  +S/tempobj predates the +Sn syntax and before you could specify the number it was always just one rev (i.e. the head rev).

Answer (score 0):

Empirically, it looks like +S is equivalent to +S1.

The p4v gui indicates this: when changing the filetype, the dropdown for "Server limits the number of revisions stored to:" maps "1" to +S, and "2" to +S2.

Also: If I manually change a filetype to +S1 using the command-line (p4 edit -t text+S1 RevisionsTest.txt), when viewed in p4v history, the +S1 becomes just +S.

Experiments with the behavior of the number of revisions stored seems to confirm that +S and +S1 are equivalent.